# On the PDE $i\tau\psi_t(x,t) + e^{-\alpha t}\psi_{xx}(x,t) = x^2e^{\alpha t}\psi(x,t)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I would like to solve or at least further understand the solution of the following PDE:

$$i\tau\psi_t(x,t) + e^{-\alpha t}\psi_{xx}(x,t) = x^2e^{\alpha t}\psi(x,t)$$

such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi^*(x,t)\psi(x,t)dx = 1$ for all $t > 0$.

This arises from Quantum Mechanics when trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for an explicitly time-dependent Hamiltonian.

I know that seperation of variables doesn't work here, because of the exponential factors that involve time. I've also thought about maybe using a Fourier Transform, but that doesn't really help in the spatial variable, because then the $x^2$ becomes a second derivative.

I would not be surprised if no analytical solution is possible here and I am forced to resort to numerical methods, but I have not given up hope yet that somebody might have an idea for a clever ansatz or a clever coordinate transform that reduces this to something more manageable.

Comment: Well, $y=x \exp( \alpha t/2)$ simplifies the 2nd and 3rd term into the "time independent" QHO equation in *y* ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it *is* separable, in the suitable variables, and reducible to a nasty eigenvalue problem for one of them.

That is, split your linear operator,
$$
0=\left (   i\tau \partial_t + e^{-\alpha t} \partial_x^2 -x^2 e^{\alpha t}        \right )\psi \\
= \left (   i\tau (\partial_t -\frac{\alpha x}{2}) +(\frac{i\tau \alpha}{2}x\partial_x + e^{-\alpha t} \partial_x^2 -x^2 e^{\alpha t} )       \right )\psi \\
\equiv (L_1 +L_2)\psi, 
$$
and set $\psi= e^{-iEt/\tau}  \phi(x ~e^{\alpha t/2})  $ for some eigenvalue constants *E* and associated functions $\phi$.

Since $L_1 \phi(x ~e^{\alpha t/2}) =0$  and $(L_1-E) e^{-iEt/\tau} =0 $, one has
$$
-E\phi (x ~e^{\alpha t/2}) =L_2 ~\phi (x ~e^{\alpha t/2}) =  \left (\frac{i\tau \alpha}{2}x\partial_x + e^{-\alpha t} \partial_x^2 -x^2 e^{\alpha t} \right )  \phi (x ~e^{\alpha t/2}),
$$
so that 
$$
-E\phi (y) = \left (\frac{i\tau \alpha}{2}y\partial_y +   \partial_y^2 -y^2   \right )  \phi (y),
$$
a potentially messy eigenvalue problem you are invited to analyze for your solutions. (It is covered in E Kamke's monumental "phone book", though...)

Comment: This is very clever. Thanks for the insight!